# Is it possible to obtain the richter grade of an earthquake with the data of an accelerometer?

Tags: measurements, earthquake

I have an accelerometer on a table that gives me the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axis acceleration in $m/s^2$ when I move the table. Is there a formula or method to pass this data to a earthquake grade in a Richter Rank?

Comment: Hola, this may be more suitable, and solved already, on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/